# Intuition for Conjugacy Classes in Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, intuition

On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class) for Conjugacy Classes, it says that "members of the same conjugacy class cannot be distinguished using the group structure alone".

*In what sense is this true?*
I can see that this is not meant to taken literally: for example, it's not true that if two elements of a group are conjugate, they act the same way in the group multiplication table.  So in what sense can conjugate elements "not be distinguished"? The best that I can come up with is that conjugate elements have the same order -- but the opposite direction is not even true in general! (i.e: $|x| = |y|$ does not imply $x$ and $y$ are conjugate) Are there other properties conjugate elements share -- properties that $x$ and $y$ share *if and only if* they are conjugate?

To be clear, I understand why conjugacy is important in certain examples. For instance:

- In $GL(n, \mathbb{F})$, for example, if two matrices are conjugate then they have the same rank, nullity, trace, determinant, and so on.
- In $S_n$, two permutations are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle type.

But in a general group $G$, I cannot see why saying "$x$ and $y$ are conjugate" is significant / what it tells us. Any clarification would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Take just two elements of a group, say $a$ and $b$. The least of group theory that you can do with them is to consider the two products $ab$ and $ba$; they might well be not equal, but they are always equivalent to each other by conjugacy, as $ba=a^{-1}(ab)a$. So, conjugacy is the equivalence relation in a group which makes undistinguishable building blocks such as $ab$ and $ba$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conjugate elements of a group, and for that matter elements that are conjugate by an automorphism, share all "purely group-theoretic properties." Some examples:

- The order of the element $\text{ord}(g) = | \langle g \rangle |$, where $\langle g \rangle$ denotes the subgroup generated by $g$
- The number of $k^{th}$ roots $\{ h \in G : h^k = g \}$, for any $k$ (and in fact more than this, e.g. the conjugacy-by-automorphism class)
- The number of ways to write $g$ as a commutator $[h, k] = hkh^{-1}k^{-1}$ (this and the previous example generalize to counting solutions to systems of equations in $G$ with $g$ as a parameter)
- The isomorphism class of the centralizer $C_G(g) = \{ h \in G : hg = gh \}$
- The isomorphism class of the normalizer $N_G( \langle g \rangle ) = \{ h \in G : h \langle g \rangle = \langle g \rangle h \}$
- Various combinations of the above constructions

Elements which are conjugate (by an inner automorphism) and not just conjugate by an automorphism share a few more properties:

- The centralizer (not just up to isomorphism but on the nose)
- The conjugacy class of the image under any group homomorphism $f : G \to H$ (e.g. a permutation representation $G \to S_n$, or a linear representation $G \to GL_n$; so conjugate elements have the same cycle type with respect to *any* permutation action and the same eigenvalues etc. with respect to *any* linear representation)
- The value when evaluated on any [character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory) (this is an if-and-only-if for finite groups: two elements $g, h$ of a finite group are conjugate iff $\chi(g) = \chi(h)$ for every irreducible character $\chi$ over $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: lovely! the bit about centralizers and representations really cleared it up. thanks.

Comment: Alas, conjugate elements do not necessarily share a centralizer. If $x,y$ are conjugate, then $C_G(x)$ and $C_G(y)$ are conjugate, but it is not necessarily the case that $C_G(x)=C_G(y)$. To see why it would be absurd for this to be true in general, note that for any element $x$, $x$ obviously commutes with itself. If $C_G(x)=C_G(y)$, then $x\in C_G(x)=C_G(y)$ and $y\in C_G(y)=C_G(x)$, so $x$ and $y$ commute. This means that if it were true in general that conjugate elements have identical centralizers, then conjugate elements must commute, but this fails spectacularly in the symmetric group.